# WITH clause not working inside a TRIGGER in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Minimal reproducible example:

```
create table t (f text);

create view v (f) as select f from t;

create trigger g instead of insert on v
begin
with w (f) as (select 'f')
insert into t select f from w;
end;
```

Gives:

> Error: near line 5: in prepare, near "insert": syntax error (1)

When this works fine:

```
create table t (f text);

with w (f) as (select 'f')
insert into t select f from w;
```

According to [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) with clause inside a trigger is supported. Not sure what's wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the same [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) you linked to, it clearly states under section **2.1**:

> Common table expression are not supported for statements inside of triggers.

Comment: Well then they should not have included the with clause in the insert-stmt scheme in the same document :/

Comment: I've never used SqlLite however my interperetation of this documentation is that those sections are for those statements in isolation, not specifically related to triggers  (since "select" also appears and what is a "select trigger"?) - granted tho, it's not clear. Just like the database, maybe this is the "lite" documentation ;-)